# Where _cluster/settings storge in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

When I change the `_cluster/settings` with es api, it will take effect immediately and will not reset after reboot.

I guess cluster_settings is persisted to a file，where can I find this file?

```
curl -X PUT 127.0.0.1:9200/_cluster/settings -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "persistent" : {
        "indices.recovery.max_bytes_per_sec" : "513mb"
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cluster settings are stored in the cluster state which is internal and you **cannot** access it directly at the file level, any change in the settings needs to be done using the `elasticsearch.yml`, which needs a restart, or using the API endpoint.

Some settings are *dynamic* and others are *static*, dynamic settings will be applied immediately after the API request, static settings need a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

cluster setting and node state of elastic node save in node.lock file in data path of elasticsearch

if you want reset node cluster setting manually just remove node.lock and nodes file